# Is @Inject really only needed for the cases when not transpiling with TS or emitDecoratorMetadata:false

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I'm reading [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) on `@Injectable` and `@Inject` and it has the following:

> Problem solved. In fact, this is exactly what **@Inject is for when not
>   transpiling with TypeScript**. If we take a look at the transpiled code
>   now, we see that all the needed metadata is generated (yeap
>   simplified).
>
> ...
>
> We can basically put any decorator on our code, as long as it’s either
>   attached to the class declaration, or to the constructor parameter. In
>   other words, we could remove @Inject again and use something else that
>   we put on the class, because that will cause TypeScript to emit
>   metadata for the constructor parameters too... Luckily, Angular comes
>   with yet another decorator we can use. @Injectable is normally used
>   for Dart metadata generation. It doesn’t have any special meaning in
>   TypeScript-land, however, it turns out to be a perfect fit for our use
>   case.

So, is my understanding correct, that:

1. If a class is used as injectable for other classes but is not dependent on any other class, it doesn't need neither @Injectable nor @Inject in the constructor
2. If a class is dependent on any other class and doesn't have any decorator used on it, it requires `@Injectable()` decorator
3. If TS is used with `emitDecoratorMetadata:true`, `@Inject` decorator is of no use
4. If TS is not used, or used with `emitDecoratorMetadata:false`, `@Inject` is the only mechanism to specify the dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, AFAIK ("dependent on any other class" see below, there are other kind of dependencies than classes)
2. Yes, but using `@Injectable()` is preferred AFAIK.
3. `@Inject()` is required when the type of the parameter doesn't match the type the providered is registered with.

```
providers: [
  MyService,
  {provide 'myservice', useClass: MyService},
  {provide myserviceOpaqueToken, useClass: MyService},
]
```

```
constructor(private myService:MyService) {} // no @Inject() required
constructor(@Inject('myservice') private myService:MyService) {} //  @Inject() used to lookup the provider by string name
constructor(@Inject(myserviceOpaqueToken) private myService:MyService) {} //  @Inject() used to lookup the provider by OpaqueToken
```

This also reveals some misconceptions in your other statements. Classes can depend on other parameters than on other classes

```
providers: [
  {provide 'myconfigvalue', useValue: '42'},
]

constructor(@Inject('myconfigvalue') private myConfigValue:string) {}
```

4. There is also the `static get parameters() { ... }` getter to specify dependencies. I guess this is still valid for using Angular2 with ES5/6 (never used it myself)

https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es6-f5551a3d6bf#.kgxjvcinv

> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app',
>   template: `
>     <ul>
>       <li *ngFor="#city of getCities()">{{ city }}</li>
>     </ul>
>   `
> })
> class AppComponent {
>   static get parameters() {
>     return [[CityService]];
>   }
>
>   constructor(cityService) {
>     this._cityService = cityService;
>   }
>
>   getCities() {
>     return this._cityService.getCities();
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer! Since we can use only `classes`,`strings` and `opaquetokens` as dependency tokens, `@Inject()` is then primarily used to inject `string` and `opaquetokens` dependecies, correct?

Comment: That's what it is normally used for, because `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `Object` can't be used as key for providers to be registered. I forgot to mention `constructor(@Inject(MyServiceBase) private myService:MyService) {}` with `class MyService extends MyServiceBase {}` and `providers: [{provide: MyServiceBase, useClass: MyService}]`. You also can't use interfaces as keys for providers (just to complete the list)

Comment: got it, appreciate you help